# How to scrape a class and if not found scrape another

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, do-while

I am using VBA to scrape a website. The scraper made by me works but I want to implement 2 more functions and don't really know how to do it. This is the code:

```
Sub pronutrition()
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
my_url = "https://www.myprotein.ro/"
ie.Visible = True
i = 20
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A20:A" & LastRow)
For Each cell In Rng

ie.navigate my_url
    Do While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Wait 1

ie.Document.getElementsByName("search")(0).Value = cell


ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("headerSearch_button")(0).Click
    Do While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Wait 2
ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i) = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("athenaProductBlock_productName")(0).innerText + ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("athenaProductBlock_fromValue")(0).innerText
    Do While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Wait 2

ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i) = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("athenaProductBlock_productName")(1).innerText + ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("athenaProductBlock_fromValue")(1).innerText
    Do While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Wait 2

ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i) = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("athenaProductBlock_productName")(2).innerText '+ ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("athenaProductBlock_priceValue")(2).innerText
    Do While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Wait 2

ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i) = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("athenaProductBlock_productName")(3).innerText '+ ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("athenaProductBlock_priceValue")(3).innerText

    Do While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Wait 2

i = i + 1
Next cell
ie.Quit
MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

First I want to search for "athenaProductBlock_fromValue" class and if it doesn't find it to search for "athenaProductBlock_priceValue", and second, if it doesn't find more than 1 or 2 products (the range is set to 4) to stop the search (right now it returns and error if it doesn't find a 2nd or a 3rd product and won't go to search the next keyword).

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Reason why it stops is because at the moment you code is presuming that all these elements will be there. Declare a `Elements` variable and capture `getElementsByClassName` result. Then check if any elements were found before attempting to `Click` on it or capture it's text. Also, you haven't provided the actual error that you are getting and which line you get it on?

Comment: The error is "Object variable or With block variable not set" when it's trying to get "athenaProductBlock_priceValue" but it can't find this class on the page because on some pages can be "athenaProductBlock_priceValue" and on other pages can be "athenaProductBlock_fromValue", that's why I need to check for one of them and if it doesn't exist to check foe the other.

Comment: Try to do what i suggested, should hopefully resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper method to extract the `HTMLCollection` returned by the `getElementsByClassName` method. You can then check if the method returned any results.

Once you get back the collection filled, it's up to you how to handle it. You can loop and fill individual cells or join the results to fill a single cell. Also, if the `Count` is less then 2, ignore it etc.

```
Private Function TryExtractElementsByClassName(ByVal ie As Object, 
                                               ByVal className As String, 
                                               ByRef objCollection As VBA.Collection) As Boolean

    'if ie is null, return false
    If ie Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    'if elements (HTMLCollection) is null, return false
    Dim elements As Object
    Set elements = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName(className)
    If elements Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    'fill collection
    Dim element As Object, idx As Long
    For idx = 0 To elements.Length
        Set element = elements(idx)
        If Not element Is Nothing Then objCollection.Add element
    Next idx

    'return
    TryExtractElementsByClassName = objCollection.Count > 0

End Function
```

To call the helper method:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    Dim objColl As New VBA.Collection

    'search single class name
    If TryExtractElementsByClassName(ie, "athenaProductBlock_priceValue", objColl) Then
        'handle results stored in objColl
    End If

    'search multiple class names separated by a space
    If TryExtractElementsByClassName(ie, "athenaProductBlock_priceValue athenaProductBlock_fromValue", objColl) Then
        'handle results stored in objColl
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is highlighted?

Comment: Solved that one by adding _, but now it shows Method Document of object IWebBrowser2 failed, and highlights     Set elements = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName(className)